# JRE for Pentaho Data Integration Tool (Kettle - Version 8.2)

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, corretto

Does Pentaho Data Integration Tool (Kettle - Version 8.2) run on Amazon Corretto JRE (or) does it specifically require Oracle JRE?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Corretto JRE is said to be based off OpenJDK. Pentaho 8.2 works with OpenJDK no issues so I would guess it will work with Amazon Corretto JRE